# Optimizing column-wise operations in a for-loop over Spark dataframe in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to apply the same set of (18 or so) transformations on each column (= quantitative continuous variable) of my Spark DataFrame (df_qc) to generate new feature for my modelling exercise.

The initial dataframe, df_qc, has some 700k row and 180 columns.

I am running a for-loop over all columns of df_qc, in each round extending the df_qc using .withColumn() function. I cache the extended dataframe after all transformation for a given column has been applied.

I localCheckpoint the dataframe after every 10 columns (to break the lineage, otherwise I run into OOM due to huge lineage).

I am clocking how much time it takes to perform the operations and I have noticed that the time that it takes to perform the set of 18 tranformations is increasing as I add more and more columns. This can be due to increasing size of df itself, but I doubt it, given that this DF is still relatively small one.

I am using PySpark API. I am running on and EMR cluster with 4 nodes, worker nodes are m4.xlarge machines.

(1) I've tried multiple different setups:

- without localCheckpointing => resulted in blowing up memory due to data lineage.
- with localCheckpointing on 10 columns (took 10 minutes), 20 columns (took 16 minutes), 40 columns (took 1h24min) ==> this 'exponential' growth in time bugs me...

When looking at stages, I see that localcheckPointing is the bottleneck.
[Spark stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJWJI.png)

even though, I cannot do it without it...
I would like to achieve a state in which I can run the set of transformation in roughly constant time for each column.

Here is a reproducable code:
(In my real-life case, I would like to run with nids=100k and nqsc=200)

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import datetime, DoubleType, FloatType, IntegerType
import itertools

#create dummy input data
nmonths  = 12     # number of distinct dates
nids     = 1000  # number of distinct IDs 
nqcs     = 5    # number of columns

id = list()
for i in range (1,nids+1):
    id = id + list(itertools.repeat(i, nmonths))

dummyData = {'ID':id
             ,'DATE':nids*[*range(1,nmonths+1)]}

for i in range(1,nqcs):
    dummyData['QC_'+str(i)] = np.random.uniform(size=nmonths*nids)

pdDF = pd.DataFrame(dummyData) 
df_qc = spark.createDataFrame(pdDF)

#df_qc.show()

# Add transformations
w = Window.partitionBy('ID')\
          .orderBy("DATE")

counter = 1
start = datetime.datetime.now()
for col in df_qc.columns[2:]:

    # 1) generate window transformations
    start_in_loop = datetime.datetime.now()
    df_qc = df_qc.withColumn(col+'_1', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=1).over(w))\
                 .withColumn(col+'_2', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=2).over(w))\
                 .withColumn(col+'_3', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=3).over(w))\
                 .withColumn(col+'_4', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=4).over(w))\
                 .withColumn(col+'_5', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=5).over(w))\
                 .withColumn(col+'_6', F.lag(df_qc[col], count=6).over(w))\
                 .withColumn('QC_DMAX'+col[2:], df_qc[col] - F.max(df_qc[col]).over(w))\
                 .withColumn('QC_DMIN'+col[2:], df_qc[col] - F.min(df_qc[col]).over(w))\
                 .withColumn('QC_DAVG'+col[2:], df_qc[col] - F.avg(df_qc[col]).over(w))\
                 .cache()

    df_qc = df_qc.withColumn('QC_AD'+col[2:]+'_1', df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_1'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_AD'+col[2:]+'_3', df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_3'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_AD'+col[2:]+'_6', df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_6'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_RD'+col[2:]+'_1', (df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_1']) / df_qc[col+'_1'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_RD'+col[2:]+'_3', (df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_3']) / df_qc[col+'_3'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_RD'+col[2:]+'_6', (df_qc[col] - df_qc[col+'_6']) / df_qc[col+'_6'])\
                 .withColumn('QC_MA'+col[2:]+'_1', (df_qc[col] + df_qc[col+'_1']) / 2)\
                 .withColumn('QC_MA'+col[2:]+'_2', (df_qc[col] + df_qc[col+'_1'] + df_qc[col+'_2']) / 3)\
                 .withColumn('QC_MA'+col[2:]+'_3', (df_qc[col] + df_qc[col+'_1'] + df_qc[col+'_2'] + df_qc[col+'_3']) / 4)\
                 .cache()

    # localcheckpointing (to break the lineage)
    if counter%10==0:
        start_checkpoint = datetime.datetime.now()
        df_qc = df_qc.localCheckpoint()
        print('- Time spent checkpointing :: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now() - start_checkpoint))

    counter += 1

    print("- Generating window tansformation | ELAPSED TIME FOR " + col + " :: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() - start_in_loop))   
print("==> TOTAL ELAPSED TIME WINDOW AGGREGATIONS :: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() - start))
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or how this type of a code could be optimized?

Many thanks!

Comment: The approach you are using not a good way to implement in Spark. In this way Spark have to read each data and save it in memory or have to write somewhere otherwise I dont think it will execute any action.  I have faced similar issue and have resolved it by joining dataframe. Could you provide details in the for of input dataframe , transformation dataframe/dict and what should be expected output and also if there is any staging Dataframe.

Comment: Dear @Nikk , thx for your reply. Ok, I will prepare a small reproducable example and post it here. Please note that I have also tried it with the joining, but it did not seem to me as an efficient way of doing it due to shuffling. I wanted to avoid shuffling, that I why I went with .withColumns()

Comment: @Nikk, I have added a reproducable piece of the code. In my realistic case, I would like to run with nids 100k and nqcs=200. I would like to get to a version of a where time increases more-less linearly with number of nqcs (in the current version, it is not the case as you can see when you run the code).